# Is there a mitzvah to honor a bechor who’s an adopted brother

Tags: halacha, family-members, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, yoreh-deah, bechor-firstborn

The Halacha states that there is a mitzvah to honor first born brothers. My question is, does this apply if the oldest brother is adopted? What if the oldest brother who is adopted is a first born from his mother? What if there is a brother who is a first born from his mother but not the oldest brother Among the family, do you have to honor both him and the biological oldest brother?

Comment: First-born brothers? Doesn't that apply for all older brothers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to the last two questions, the SA [YD 240:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.240.22?lang=bi) states that a first born to either your father or your mother is included:

> חייב אדם בכבוד אחיו הגדול בין שהוא אחיו מאביו בין שהוא אחיו מאמו

> A person is obligated to honor his older brother, whether he is his brother from his father or whether he is his brother from his mother

From inference, it would seem, that the requirement is biological so adopted children wouldn’t be included.